# Visual Studio 2010 Document Formatting Rules

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting

I know that in the Tools > Options (Text Editor > CSS > Format) menu I can choose between three types of document formatting for CSS files (compact, semi-expanded and expanded) as well as capitalization.

A decision has been made in my organization to implement a formatting structure in XML files, where the attributes for an element line up on successive lines like this:

```
<ElementName attribute1="someValue"
             attribute2="someOtherValue" 
             attribute3="yaddayaddayadda" />
```

1. Is there a way to define custom formatting rules for XML files so that when I format the document with Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D I get the desired result?
2. Is there a way to define a "rule" that will insert the correct number of spaces on the second line after I finish typing the first attribute?
3. Is there a way to have code snippets follow these rules when pasting in the snippet?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Scott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set this option:**

Tools > Options > Text Editor > XML > Formatting > Attributes > Align attributes each on a separate line.

**Go to XML document and use:**

Edit > Advanced > Format document.
(<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to customize XML document formatting to this level in Visual Studio.  It only allows for much coarser grained formatting.

I think your only option is to use another tool to ensure formatting of documents and have that tool run on build / save of the documents in question.  Essentially StyleCop for your XML documents.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, obviously... but thanks just the same.  +1 for that rapid response.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See my answer for how to automatically format XML with aligned attributes in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.